# In libgdx model-loader demo font.draw() is not putting "fps" text on screen

Tags: java, text, libgdx

I am starting to work with libgdx.
I opened the example model-loader in trunk ([StillModelViewerGL20.java](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/extensions/model-loaders/model-loaders/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/test/StillModelViewerGL20.java)).  In the source I see this code in the `render` callback:

```
batch.begin();  
font.draw(batch, "fps: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond(), 20, 30);    
batch.end();
```

But I do not see any text on screen. Is there something I need to fix in this example to see text displayed?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the screen size is smaller than 20,30. Try to draw on 0, 0.

Answer (score 1):

check the order in which you draw your objects, and if this is corrected by changing.